# Testing before_destroy method with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Hi I'm having trouble of how should I test this case scenario

models/checklist.rb

```
before_destroy :destroyable?

def destroyable?
 raise "Error" if phase.companies.count > 0
end
```

spec/models/checklist_spec.rb

```
describe 'triggers' do
 describe 'destroyable?' do
  it 'should raise error if checklist phase has companies' do
    company = create(:company)
    company2 = create(:company)
    phase = create(:phase, company_ids: [company.id, company2.id])

    checklist = create(:checklist, phase: phase)

    expect(checklist.destroy).to raise_error(RuntimeError)
  end
 end
end
```

I'm getting this error: **RuntimeError:
       Error**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the code raising the error in a block,

```
expect { checklist.destroy }.to raise_error(RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 7):

Exceptions should be used for exceptional situations, your situation is not exceptional. For rails 4 you should return false and for rails 5 you should call `throw(:abort)` to prevent the record for being destroyed.

You can add an error (to have some feedback) and then abort if the condition is true:

```
before_destroy :destroyable?

def destroyable?
  return true if phase.companies.count == 0
  errors.add(:companies, 'is not empty')
  throw(:abort)
end
```

Now you can test this like:

```
checklist.destroy
expect(checklist).not_to be_destroyed
expect(checklist.errors[:companies]).to eq 'is not empty'
```

Check the Callbacks DOC, the "Cancelling callbacks" section https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

EDIT:
If you still want to have an exception when the record is not destroyed, then the before_destroy callback would be the same but you call `destroy!` instead (note the "!" bang) which raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed` exception.

Is counterintuitive to raise an exception as `destroy` cancellation since it's not meant to work that way by convention.